# switch between ofEpochMilli and ofEpochSecond

Tags: java, java-8

In my application one of third party API returning timestamp in epoch.

Sometime it returns epoch time in seconds and sometime in miliseconds not confirmed. My application using below code to
convert it to java date and display to user but when I am receiving time in miliseconds it is failing on year.

```
    String time = "1519377196185"; //Time in miliseconds
    //String time = "1521575819"; //Time in seconds.
    String timeZone = "US/Pacific";
    long epochdate = Long.parseLong(time);
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMM dd, yyyy hh:mm a");
    LocalDateTime date34 =
                Instant.ofEpochSecond(epochdate)
              .atZone(ZoneId.of(timeZone))
              .toLocalDateTime();
    String date = date34.format(formatter).toString();
    System.out.println("date : " + date);
```

if I use `Instant.ofEpochMilli(epochdate)` for miliseconds then it is working fine. So my question is how I can know that coming timestamp is in miliseconds or seconds so on that basis I will switch between `ofEpochMilli` and `ofEpochSecond`

Comment: *it is failing on year*: what does that mean, precisely? Your code works fine here. Regarding your question: I have a hard time understanding why a (decent, useful) API would return the same information in two different formats. Are you sure the documentation doesn't say which format it uses? If it really is as you describe, all you can do is use some heuristics. For example, if the date, parsed by assuming the value is in millis, is less than 1975, then it probably means the milliseconds are in fact seconds.

Comment: Sounds like you should get rid of that third party API if it isn't able to give "stable" results.. which time does it return? Or what kind of time?

Comment: By the way, **do not use `LocalDateTime` for a moment**. That class purposely lacks any concept of time zone or offset-from-UTC, so it cannot represent a moment, and is *not* a point on the timeline. Stick with the `ZonedDateTime` object returned from call to `Instant::atZone`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Year Offset**

I would try to parse first the date as seconds, given that if the date is in millis the year would be something extremely big (in this case 50000), then if the year is not greater than the year defined offset (e.g. 3000), that date is returned, otherwise the date is returned as millis.

```
public ZonedDateTime getZonedDateTime(String time) {
    long longTime = Long.parseLong(time), yearOffset = 3000L;
    String timeZone = "US/Pacific";
    ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of(timeZone);
    ZonedDateTime zdt = Instant.ofEpochSecond(longTime).atZone(zoneId);
    if (zdt.getLong(ChronoField.YEAR_OF_ERA) >= yearOffset) {
        return Instant.ofEpochMilli(longTime).atZone(zoneId);
    } else {
        return zdt;
    }
}
```

Using the functions prints:

```
getZonedDateTime("1519377196185"); // 2018-02-23T01:13:16.185-08:00[US/Pacific]
getZonedDateTime("1521575819"); // 2018-03-20T12:56:59-07:00[US/Pacific]
```

**Margin of Error**

Any method that you decide to use, would have the possibility of an error and that the date is transformed incorrectly, specially when the date is in milliseconds and is too close of the epoch `1970-01-01T00:00:00Z`.

The margin errors using the year offset of `3000` would be:

- When the date is originally in **milliseconds** in the range from **1970-01-01T00:00:00Z** until **1971-01-12T04:48:00Z**

  - Would be considered as date in seconds
- When the date is originally in **seconds** and the date is equal or after **3000-01-01T00:00:00Z** (improbable date in normal apps)

  - Would be considered as date in milliseconds

**Calculate the range of error in milliseconds dates**

You can calculate the range of error for dates originally in milliseconds with:

```
Instant.ofEpochMilli(LocalDateTime.of(3000, 1, 1, 0, 0) // year = 3000
    .toEpochSecond(ZoneOffset.UTC)); // 1971-01-12T04:48:00Z
```

Comment: Thanks Jose for your answer and suggestion, it works and using same way. Thanks again. Sorry for late reply.

Comment: Thanks, @ppb, for accepting the answer (on the tick mark) so we all can see what worked. Please consider accepting answers to some of your other (recent) questions too. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

One easy (temporary, sort of) solution would be to just check the length of your `time` `String`.  If the length is equal to `13`, then it represents milliseconds.  This will be true until `1 ms` after `2286-11-20T17:46:39.999Z`, which is a long time from now.  The time in seconds would take even more time to reach a length of `13`.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this other way by converting epoch in seconds to epoch in milliseconds and apply only `Instant.ofEpochMilli()` for both:

```
String time = "1519377196185"; //Time in miliseconds or seconds

if(time.length() == 10) { // length of epoch in seconds is 10
    time = time + "000";
}

String timeZone = "US/Pacific";

long epochdate = Long.parseLong(time);

DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMM dd, yyyy hh:mm a");

LocalDateTime date34 = Instant.ofEpochMilli(time)
                              .atZone(ZoneId.of(timeZone))
                              .toLocalDateTime();

String date = date34.format(formatter).toString();

System.out.println("date: " + date);
```

Answer (score 0):

## Inspect length of String input

As stated by Jacob G. [his Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49394838/642706), check the length.

```
String input = "1519377196185";  // Milliseconds since epoch.
//String input = "1519377196" ;  // Seconds since epoch.
Instant instant = null;
int length = input.length();
switch ( length )
{
    case 13:
        instant = Instant.ofEpochMilli( Long.parseLong( input ) );
        break;
    case 10:
        instant = Instant.ofEpochSecond( Long.parseLong( input ) );
        break;
    default:
        throw new IllegalStateException( "Unexpected length of input text for count-from-epoch number: " + input + ". Message # 2188d054-5720-4393-9b18-829913d7ba1c." );
}
System.out.println( input + " ➞ " + instant.toString() );  // Generate a String representing textually the value of the `Instant` object.
```

> 1519377196185 ➞ 2018-02-23T09:13:16.185Z

Or:

> 1519377196 ➞ 2018-02-23T09:13:16Z

### `ZonedDateTime`

To move from UTC in an `Instant` to some particular time zone, provide the context of a time zone (`ZoneId`) to get a `ZonedDateTime` object.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Africa/Tunis" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone( z ) ;
```

> zdt.toString(): 2018-02-23T10:13:16.185+01:00[Africa/Tunis]

### `LocalDateTime` - not appropriate here

The **`LocalDateTime` class is the wrong class** to use, as seen in the Question. This class purposely lacks any concept of time zone or offset-from-UTC. So it does *not* represent a moment, and is *not* a point on the timeline. This class represents *potential* moments along a range of about 26-27 hours.

Use `LocalDateTime` only when the zone/offset is unknown (a terrible situation) or when you need an indefinite value such as “Christmas starts on first moment of December 25, 2018”.